# Как удобнее хранить миграции в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, migrate

У меня есть проект на Yii2. Проект довольно большой и уже накопилось много миграций. Это стало причиной тому, что при создании миграции надо долго крутить вниз, что бы ее отредактировать.

Я знаю, что можно изменить папку, где будет создаваться миграция и потом так же выполнить с этой папки. Думал сделать так, но тут есть возможность потом о них забыть.

Как сделать правильно? Есть ли какой то способ?

Comment: А в чём идея и смысл хранить все все созданные  миграции за всё время?

Comment: Если проект долгоиграющий, то можно каждый месяц, например, делать дамп БД (хотя это надо делать чаще конечно) и удалять миграции за прошлые месяца. Вот и всё. В случае если всё пойдёт крахом или новый чел придёт - давать ему свежий дамп

Comment: Просто если разработка зашла слишком далеко, то вряд ли кто-то будет откатываться в самое начало...для чего-то.... Но если и будет (вдруг там было что-то критическое)....на такие случае есть системы контроля версий, которые хранят снимки проекта и тогда можно перейти на коммит, когда были ещё все миграции и откатиться и посмотреть что не так было

Comment: то есть, нормальной практикой является то, что бы просто удалять старые миграции?

Comment: Не знаю, какой это практикой является. Но чисто логически в них никакого смысла. Зачем держать в проекте миграции, которым уже больше года например? Какой практический смысл будет нести?

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите в строну [Phinx](https://phinx.org)

Его удобство в установке через composer, быстром создании файлов-миграций через команду в консоли.
Возможно, в начале придется покопаться с настройкой, но в сети полно мануалов.
Каждый файл - одно изменение в бд. А все миграции, что у вас были раньше, можно скопом закинуть в первый файл. Структура папок с файлами: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]